# Why does trap ERR behaviour differ over bash versions 3 and 4?

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling, trap

## Background

Execute the following code in bash 3, 4 and 5 respectively, and you will get differing results.

```
(function handle_error () { echo ERROR; }; trap handle_error ERR; (exit 1))
```

Imagine that `(exit 1)` is a command you call which might fail. In this case it always fails, but that doesn't really matter. You would like `handle_error` to be called when it exits with a non-zero exit code. According to the manual, this is exactly what `trap handle_error ERR` should do.

## Problem

I have a local system with a version of bash 3, and a remote system with a completely different operating system with a version of bash 4.

- bash 3.2.57(1), 3.2.48(1): Returns no output. Excerpt from `man bash` for the `trap` builtin:

  > If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a simple command has a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions...
- bash 4.4.23(1), 4.4.12(1): prints `ERROR` as expected. Excerpt from `man bash` for the `trap` builtin:

  > If  a  sigspec  is  ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions...
- bash 5.0.2(1): prints `ERROR` as expected.

The documentation leads me to think that the behaviour should be the same over both versions, but it isn't.

I logged onto `#bash` on Freenode, and verified there as well that this behaviour differs in the same way over all major versions 3, 4 and 5 with their shell bot (nick `shbot`), which allows you to specify the major version. This shell bot happens to run on a different operating system to both systems which I have tried it on, with differing minor versions over the same major versions of bash which I have access to.

## Question

Could anyone point to an authoritative source which explains why this behaviour differs over versions 3, 4 and 5 of bash? I find it hard to believe this this is a bug. There must be another reason which I am missing.

Comment: Hmm... Testing this in Bash 5.0 shows that it prints `ERROR`.  Setting `BASH_COMPAT` to e.g. `3.2` does not change this, so it must (?) be related to a fixed bug or similar, in-between release 3 and 4 somewhere. Do you have more exact release numbers than just `3` and `4`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact versions, and I've tested on version 5 as well now.

Comment: Obviously `exit` is a shell built-in; otherwise your script wouldn't stop. So strictly *after* `exit` the shell has little chance to do anything, and *before* it would be just magic.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a bug in Bash 3.2.

I can't find an entry in [the changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) that would directly match that. There's 
only a vague mention about changing the behavior of the `errexit` option to match POSIX consensus (item `l` in the change from bash-4.0-rc1 to bash-4.0-release).

That may be related, as there's a similar issue with `errexit`, this doesn't trigger it in Bash 3.2, but does in Bash 4.0 (it should print nothing, since the shell should exit when the subshell command fails):

```
$ ./bash3.2 -c 'set -e; (exit 1); echo end.'
end.
```

Note that the issue here seems to be the subshell, as this works in both versions:

```
$ ./bash3.2 -c 'trap "echo ERROR" ERR; false'
ERROR
```

Comment: Interesting to see the subshell aspect. I wondered whether the subshell was resetting the traps on return, but `(trap "echo ERROR" ERR; (exit 1); trap -p)` returns `trap -- 'echo ERROR' ERR` on bash 3.2.48.

Comment: What about "b.  Fixed a bug that caused subshells to free trap strings associated with inherited signals." in bash-4.4-rc1 to bash-4.4-beta2? The trap still seems to be around though.

Comment: @justinpc, I tried with 3.2.57(1)-release and 4.0.0(1)-release, so a change in 4.4 is too late